# How to fix a dpkg broken by the Brother MFC-7340 deb driver

Tags: drivers, package-management

I'm getting an apt-get error that says

`E: The package brmfc7340lpr needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

The brmfc7340lpr is a printer driver -- it's a local deb file. Doing a dpkg or apt-get purge doesn't work, neither does `apt-get install -f` .

How do I reinstall a package from a local deb file?

Output:

```
box-name% sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for username: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package brmfc7340lpr needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
box-name% sudo apt-get purge brmfc7340lpr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package brmfc7340lpr needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
box-name% sudo dpkg --purge brmfc7340lpr 
dpkg: error processing brmfc7340lpr (--purge):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brmfc7340lpr
box-name% sudo dpkg --install brmfc7340lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
Selecting previously deselected package brmfc7340lpr.
(Reading database ... 725204 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace brmfc7340lpr 2.0.2-1 (using .../brmfc7340lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement brmfc7340lpr ...
start: Unknown job: lpd
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
start: Unknown job: lpd
dpkg: error processing brmfc7340lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb (--install):
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
start: Unknown job: lpd
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
brmfc7340lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb
box-name% sudo apt-get install -f                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package brmfc7340lpr needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
box-name%
```

Comment: You might want to rename your question. It makes your problem sound a bit too generic. You're real question isn't how to reinstall just any local deb, but how to handle a very specific problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always (re)install a package using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg --install local-file.deb
```

In order to make a "clean room" installation, you can first purge the package and then install it again:

```
dpkg --purge brmfc7340lpr
dpkg --install brmfc7340lpr*.deb
```

You might need to add option `--force-depends` during purge, if some other package depends on `brmfc7340lpr`.

**Update:** Based on the transcript you posted, it seems that the
 `brmfc7340lpr` package cannot be (re)installed because its
 post-removal script is erroring out.

Those files are stored in directory `/var/lib/dpkg/info`; for each
package `X`, there can be any one of these scripts:

- `X.postinst` run *after* the package has been installed, e.g., to
  start services provided by the package.
- `X.prerm` run *before* removing/purging the package, e.g., to
  ensure that daemons provided by the package are stopped.
- `X.postrm` run *after* the package has been removed, e.g., to
  signal any service optionally using the package that it is no
  longer available.  (For instance, a printer driver package might
  want to signal cpus/lpr to remove printers depending on that
  specific driver.)

Now, this `brmfc7340lpr` package seems to try to (re)start the `lpd`
printer daemon upon removal, which won't work as Ubuntu uses CUPS
instead: you should definitely look for a CUPS-compatible printer
driver -- see the link in Jorge Castro's answer. (I think this is a
bug in the package, as it should not restart the `lpd` service
unconditionally, but just reload it *if it's already running*.)

The best option to go forward comes from [this launchpad
answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/106377):

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/cpus /etc/init.d/lpd
```

This will effectively (re)start CUPS when the `lpd` service is instead
searched for.

Otherwise, I only see two options, both rather unpleasant:

1. Either edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/brmfc7340lpr.postrm` script,
   and comment out the line that is invoking `/etc/init.d/lpd start`
   (or `restart` or `stop`), (e.g., just replace it with `/bin/true`).
   Another option is to just place `exit 0` as the first non-comment
   line in the script. This would be my favorite, but requires a bit
   of confidence with editing shell scripts.
2. Install `lpr`, purge the `brmfc6340lpr` package, purge `lpr`: this
   requires a bit of attention as `lpr` conflicts with the default
   Ubuntu printer spooling system CUPS:

   a. `sudo aptitude install lpr` (this will remove `cups-bsd` and
     `ubuntu-desktop` as a side effect)

   b. `sudo aptitude purge brmfc7340lpr lpr` (should work now)

   c. `sudo aptitude install cups-bsd ubuntu-desktop` (restore system
     to its original state)

Comment: dpkg --install doesn't work

Comment: @Roman What error message do you get?  Does `--purge` first and then `--install` work?

Comment: @Roman updated with some specific instructions that might help.   I agree with andrewsomething's comment that this no longer looks a generic question and should be renamed.

Comment: I ended up renaming lpd to nlpdn temporarily to install it.

Answer (score 5):

Riccardo's solution should work, I am guessing the problem lies here:

`start: Unknown job: lpd`

Guess 1: It looks like the deb is trying to restart a service which isn't running and erroring out. Try installing the `lpr` package from the repositories and then installing the deb and see if that works.

Guess 2: It sounds like you're trying to install a deb from a website for a brother 7340 printer: [This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BrotherDriverPackaging) might be a good starting point if you want to split it off into another question.

Comment: /etc/init.d/lpd start                                                                                                                     start: Unknown job: lpd

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I ran into the same problem. Turns out I followed some irrelevant information and created a `/etc/init.d/lpd` file as a softlink to `/etc/init.d/cups`
The `.postrm` script checks for lpd and if it exists, tries to start the service.
After I deleted the softlinked lpd file in the init.d directory, the package installation and removal went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here appears to be that the package has managed to get itself half-installed, but now its maintainer scripts are all faililng (due to being unable to start the lpd service).

You should be able to resolve this by editing the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/brmfc7340lpr.postrm` file and commenting out (by adding `#` to the start of the line) the line which is trying to start lpd (or just comment out everything).  You should then be able to run `dpkg --configure -a` to get the package properly installed before you can remove it.

You might need to edit more of the packages maintainer scripts in order to remove the package - they'll all be in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`, and they'll be named something like `brmfc7340lpr.X` where `X` can be one of `preinst`, `postinst`, `prerm`, `postrm`.

This is an example of the sort of havoc a poorly written package can wreak.