# How can I remove a dpkg broken by the Brother MFC-8840 deb driver?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, brother, purge, software-uninstall

I can't seem to remove a package.

I've tried dpkg --purge and apt-get purge. Neither seem to actually remove the package, however. The package is mfc8840dlpr (1.1.2-1).

Is there any way I can make this question clearer, or more specific?

Someone seems to have solved a similar problem, as follows, but it doesn't have much about how to actually remove the package:

[How to fix a dpkg broken by the Brother MFC-7340 deb driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5058/how-to-fix-a-dpkg-broken-by-the-brother-mfc-7340-deb-driver)

Has anyone else come across this problem with a Brother printer driver .deb installation?

The output from my attempts follows:

```
(Reading database ... 471289 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mfc8840dlpr (1.1.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: /etc/init.d/lpd: not found
dpkg: error processing package mfc8840dlpr (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfc8840dlpr
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ dpkg --purge mfc8840dlpr
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

$ sudo dpkg --purge mfc8840dlpr
(Reading database ... 471289 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mfc8840dlpr (1.1.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: /etc/init.d/lpd: not found
dpkg: error processing package mfc8840dlpr (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfc8840dlpr

$ sudo dpkg --purge mfc8840dlpr

$ sudo apt-get purge mfc8840dlpr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mfc8840dlpr:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 471289 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mfc8840dlpr (1.1.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.postrm: /etc/init.d/lpd: not found
dpkg: error processing package mfc8840dlpr (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfc8840dlpr
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the package and could reproduce the problem.

This command has solved the problem:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8840dlpr.*
```

This removes the installation files the mfc8840dlpr package, which will prevent any further automatic attempts to complete installation. This will also leave the system in a state of thinking that the mfc8840dlpr package is installed, when really it is perhaps not.

Comment: I will try this out and report the results.

Comment: My new output: https://cryptobin.org/j51973j7 (passphrase:QR7HHcT1tlm2Zv3vCNw50wILEHUaTqDfDMu20TOWEy/31NrB8D6e4mUKggbI8xmG)

Comment: Wow!  How did you reproduce *this*???

Comment: @Fabby simply install the package and you would have the same problem :)